# ParseObject: Is there any way how to create JSON from ParseObject?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, parse-platform

I want to create JSON from ParseObject in my App. Usually If I need to pass object from one class to another, I pass `objectId` to bundle and I simply call query and return this object. Problem is if you create new `ParseObject` in offline mode. Calling `saveEventually` on new `ParseObject` will not add `objectId`. ObjectId is `null` that means I cant query object. The best way would be to send whole `ParseObject` as `String` to `Bundle` and simply recreate it. This is how I worked with `JSON` objects in past. `ParseObject.toString()` doesnt work as `JSONObject`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think there is no easy way to do that through the SDK. You'd need to create your own serialization function, going through all keys and creating the json.

Answer (score -1):

You can call .toJSON() on a Parse Object.

> `toJSON() → {Object}`
>   Returns a JSON version of the object suitable for
>   saving to Parse.
>
> Returns: Type: Object

Source:
http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/2.7.1/Parse.Object.html#toJSON

Comment: I dont have this function available in Kotlin (Android platform)